Screen-Saver: Issues to Turn-Off Display
I'm using an old Gateway NE56R Notebook with a fresh new Debian 12.7 LXDE and trying to set the screen-saver to turn-off the display after 1 minute of user inactivity.
For that, I've set the following at the screen-saver gui (XScreenSaver Settings):

Blank Screen Only Mode
Blank After 1 minute
Cycle After 0 minute
Power-Management Disabled (ie: box uncheck)
Quick Power-Off in Blank Only Mode

Unfortunately, it did not work. After 1 minute the screen turned blank but the display was still on (ie: backlight on).
I have already tried several other settings, including via xset, and switching xscreensaver daemon on/off, but neither worked. Briefly:

The display doesn't turn-off (ie: blank screen but backlight still on); OR
If the display turns off, the whole system randomly reboot/turn-off after a while (somewhere between 0~1000 seconds).

Question
How to set the screen-saver to turn-off the display after XX minutes ???
What am I missing? What is going on? Ideas?

Debug Examples
Example 1 (xscreensaver daemon ON, AC power):
root@debian:~# xset q
[...]
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  no    allow exposures:  no
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
[...]
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 600    Off: 600
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
root@debian:~# xset dpms force off

Display turns-off then notebook reboot.
Example 2 (xscreensaver daemon ON, battery):
root@debian:~# xset q
[...]
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  no    allow exposures:  no
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
[...]
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 600    Off: 600
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
root@debian:~# xset dpms force off

Display turns-off then notebook turns-off.
Example 3 (xscreensaver daemon OFF, AC power):
root@debian:~# xset q
[...]
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  no    allow exposures:  no
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
[...]
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 60
  DPMS is Disabled
root@debian:~# xset dpms force off

Display turns-off then notebook reboot after 250 seconds.
